# How do I use @media in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm confused on how media queries are written in SASS. I've tried this line of code, but it throws me an error:

```css
@media screen (max-width: 1550px) 
  #server-name
    left: 80%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `and` keyword. You can read more about it [here](https://designshack.net/articles/css/sass-and-media-queries-what-you-can-and-cant-do)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1550px)
    #server-name
        left: 80%
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not SASS but pure CSS problem. You have a type error because the `and` keyword is missing into the media query.

In pure `CSS` (what you'll have). You want that

```css
#server-name {
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #server-name {
    left: 80%;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="server-name">My name</div>
```

So in SASS

```
@media screen (max-width: 1550px) 
  #server-name
    left: 80%
```

Comment: Showing how to do it in CSS doesn't really answer the question of how to do it in SASS.

Comment: The question title is "How do I use @media in SASS?". The first sentence of the question is "I'm confused on how media queries are written in SASS". It is a SASS question!

Comment: I know how to do it in SCSS or CSS. I have asked how I may do it in SASS.

Comment: So my reply is: "You have a typo error, add the `and` keyword

Comment: My addintional point was "SASS don't care about your media query because it's CSS... add varaible on it like on the SASS documentation and the compilator will have work to do.. here he doing nothing.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. But, just say that I have a typo next time :P

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to give you more, I don't want to just give you the solution but inform you that typo was a CSS typo (even if you do LESS or SASS), to understand this error will also append if you try to do it later with pure CSS or Less.

Comment: Typos are off-topic anyway, next time point out in a comment, and vtc

Answer (score 1):

Maere here are a few examples of use in SASS. Note I am using SASS syntax and not SCSS
1st you create your variables for widths

```
$mobile: 568px
$tablet: 768px
$desktop: 1024px
```

Then you create your mixins

```
=desktop
  @media screen and (min-width: $desktop)
    @content

=tablet
   @media screen and (min-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $desktop - 1px)
    @content

=mobile
  @media screen and (max-width: $tablet - 1px)
    @content
```

Then you can use these mixins anyplace. Use them on containers, the body element, wherever needed

```
.m-boxes-box
  max-width: 500px
  flex: 1 2
  min-height: 250px
  background-color: $soft-peach
  margin: 10px 0

  +tablet
    min-width: 50%
  +mobile
    min-width: 100%
```